# Display Featured Posts Grid on Static Page (Gazette)

Tags: posts, theme-development, pages

I'm using the Gazette theme which has a jet pack enabled featured posts grid when the front page is set to show latest posts.

I would like to use a static page instead of recent posts, but keep the featured posts grid.

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure this out with a little moral support from the community

Link to answer - [Display Featured Posts Grid on Static Page (Gazette)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236425/display-featured-posts-grid-on-static-page-gazette#answer-236518)

---

Demo: https://gazettedemo.wordpress.com/

Source: https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/themes/download/gazette.zip

**Code parts associated with the featured posts**

@ index.php

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

@ functions.php line 197

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'gazette-featured-content', 
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/featured-content.js', 
array( 'jquery' ), '20150507', true );
```

@ featured-content.php

```
$featured_posts = gazette_get_featured_posts();
if ( empty( $featured_posts ) ) {
    return;
}
?>
    <?php
        foreach ( $featured_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );

             // Include the featured content template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'featured-post' );
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

@ content-featured-post.php

```
/**
 * The template for displaying featured posts on the front page
 */
<?php
    // Output the featured image.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'gazette-featured-content-thumbnail' );
    }
?>
```

@ inc/jetpack.php line 22

```
add_theme_support( 'featured-content', array(
    'filter'      => 'gazette_get_featured_posts',
    'description' => __( 'Omitted', 'gazette' ),
    'max_posts'   => 6,
) );
```

@ js/featured-content.js line 24

```
var featuredContent, header, primary;
featuredContent = $( '#featured-content' );
header = $( '#masthead' );
primary = $( '#primary' );

if ( ! featuredContent.length ) {
    return;
}
```

@ js/header.js line 24

```
function headerStyle() {
    var featuredContent, featuredContentHeight;

    featuredContent = $( '#featured-content' );
    featuredContentHeight = 0;
    if ( featuredContent.length ) {
        featuredContentHeight = featuredContent.outerHeight();
    }

    if ( $( '.site-branding' ).outerWidth() === 0 ) {
        $( 'body' ).addClass( 'no-branding' );
    } else {
        $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'no-branding' );
    }
```

These are all the references I found to the featured posts grid layout.

How can I modify to display the grid on the homepage setup as a static page?

**Notes**

I added this to the page.php and it does show up in the source for static, but simply does not display.

```
if ( is_page(35) ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bingo. I added the featured content template (as originally and later suggested by @user53340) to the page.php with a condition so the featured grid would only display on the page I designate.

**Add to page.php**

```
if ( is_page(ID) ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
}
```

After changing the front page display to my static page I noticed the featured content was being output in the source, however it was not showing up on the page itself.

I realized the body classes determined if this would work or not. All I had to do is add `blog` to the body class for that page. The front page display sets the body class to `page` for static page and `blog` for posts page.

Using the code below I appended the `blog` class to the body.

```
function add_blog_to_body_class($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'blog';
        return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','add_blog_to_body_class');
```

I am able to set my static page & have my featured posts grid :D

Comment: Please accept your own answer to prevent the system marking this question as unresolved.

Comment: I will in 23 (and counting) hours, when the "system" will allow it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question which is to be honest a little vague, you should be able to change if `( is_home() )` to if `( is_front_page() )` This will display the 'featured-content' template part on a static front page (i.e a home page) instead of the blog page. In Wordpress `is_home` = blog home page and `is_front_page` = static front page. A little confusing, but if you think WordPress was originally made for blogging, it makes perfect sense. is_home explained [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) is_front_page explained [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

EDIT: If you want the featured grid to display everywhere, you should be able to remove the if statement so it just reads `get_template_part( 'featured-content' );` that's assuming I have understood you correctly, and based on the limited code you have supplied. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work. Here's a direct link. The index.php is the posts page with the featured area, page.php is where I believe I would have the featured area using `if (is_page('ID'))`  https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/themes/download/gazette.zip

Comment: Have you tried if (is_page('slug')) for example if (is_page('about')) so the slug is the URL friendly name of your page title. You will need to have the right permalink structure set in Wordpress to use the title as the slug I believe, but is_page('') should also work with the id. You should still be able to just use get_template_part() without the if statement and that should work. If your link is to the files, I will download and check in a moment for you.

Comment: Good morning, I will take another look into this issue shortly and share what I've tried. I greatly appreciate your insight :)

Comment: get_template_part() is definitely working. The issue is with the JavaScript file. When you use get_template_part() I can see the HTML is there, it's just the js that is stopping it from rendering. That's what you need to look at.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it may not be called for pages?

Comment: I just tested both static front page and blog posts setup and the `wp-content/themes/gazette-wpcom/js/featured-content.js` is loading on both. I did find that `wp-content/themes/gazette-wpcom/js/posts` loads on blog posts and not front page setup. In both occasions there are no console errors.

Comment: In the functions.php I commented out conditions for the posts script. `//if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'gazette-posts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/posts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20150507', true );
 //}`

So I don't know where to look if it's js. (The lines are broken so only the condition is commented out, not the `wp_enqueue_script` itself.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I figured it out! Posted answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Nice one. Glad you got it working and I could be of some help.